# How to locate a specific row in a data table

Tags: vb.net

My objective is to locate the primary key based on the users input.

The table content is as follows: UserID,account, password.

userID is set as primary key and integer type.

account is set as varchar type.

password is set as varchar type.

Here is the code I've got at the moment to validate user input.

```
Dim account As String = txtAcc.Text
    Dim password As String = txtPss.Text


    For Each Me.dr In atadap.GetData
        If dr.Item(1) = account And dr.Item(2) = password Then
            **[retrieve userID for specified data row]**
            MsgBox("Access granted!")
            Me.Hide()
            frmMenu.Show()
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox("Access denied!")
            txtAcc.Text = ""
            txtPss.Text = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Here are the links which I've used in my research:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx

But yet still couldn't figure out how to do it. Any help would be very appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exit the `For each` loop on the first datarow, that is why you will never find the result unless the record sits at the top of the datatable.

I don't know why you need to read each rows to check for the specific row. However, if that's a requirement on your part, change your code to this:

```
Dim account As String = txtAcc.Text
Dim password As String = txtPss.Text
Dim userFound as Boolean = False
Dim userId as Integer

For Each Me.dr In atadap.GetData
    If dr.Item(1) = account And dr.Item(2) = password Then
        userId = dr.Item(0) ' save the userId in a variable
        userFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If userFound then
    MsgBox("Access granted! Your User ID is " & userId)
    Me.Hide()
    frmMenu.Show()
Else
    MsgBox("Access denied!")
    txtAcc.Text = ""
    txtPss.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: That's odd, your answer is same as @Chris has presented. However, today it's working. Both answers given are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

does:

```
userId = dr.Item(0)
```

return the ID?

Comment: It does return the userID, however it returns only the first entry within the column. What I need to achieve is to retrieve userID based on the account and password entered.

Comment: Instead of looping through the whole table. Why not just query the database once. What SQL are you using to fill your dataset?

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2008. Looping through the table is part of the requirements I'm subjected to.

Comment: Hmm. And what values do you have in account, password and the first row of data?

Comment: here is the string I use to enter new entries to table accounts.       'objCmd = New SqlCommand("insert into accounts(account,password) values ('" & txtnAcc.Text & "','" _
                                        & txtnPass.Text & "')", objCon)'